# Does every polyhedral graph have a path cover with non-empty paths?

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra, planar-graphs

I'm looking to prove or disprove the following conjecture:

Every [polyhedral graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_graph) has a [path cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_cover) with vertex disjoint, non-zero (length $\ge 1$) paths.

Any pointers to literature are appreciated.
Thanks.

Some background: the conjecture is not true for arbitrary/planar/3-connected graphs, counterexamples include any [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) where one of the partitions has < n/3 nodes, for example a [claw](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Star_(graph_theory)&redirect=no).